# How do you convert a range of integers to strings

Tags: python, string, list, integer, range

So my problem here is that I have a  range(0, 100)
How do I make a range like this into a range of string numbers?

Comment: [str(i) for i in range(100)]

Answer (score 0):

you can transform a number to a string

like this:

```
import random

 x = str(random.randint(0, 100))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s = ""
for i in range(0,10):
    s = s + str(i)
```

Output:

```
>>> s
"0123456789"
```